# how to backup MacOS under bootcamp windows7?

Tags: time-machine, bootcamp, partition, windows

Background: My OSX partition was corrupted in some way by bootcamp or the paragon i was running on it. Similar incidents has happened twice before, but I don't remember if the triggering conditions were exactly the same.

This particular time, I initially had windows 7 on bootcamp go into sleep mode. However, I forgot about this and thought it was regularly shut down, so after pressing power button I directly pressed alt to boot into MacOSX. It booted correctly but I noticed that the bootcamp partition was not loaded (through Paragon). The status said the partition was in dwell mode so I didnt do anything to them, thinking a reboot would solve it at any time.

I later restarted into bootcamp and the windows system resumed from the previous sleep mode also without any problem. However, a few files I saved during the last time in OSX became corrupted. At the same time, OSX was also no longer able to function, presumably because some of its system files in use were also corrupted during the last session. Other files that had been there unchanged since earlier, do appear still intact.

Now the disk utility under cmd+r cannot repair the disk, and will have to format the partition in order to reinstall the system. However, since I suspect only a small portion of system files have actually been lost (those altered when osx was loaded the last time); in order not to lose applications, I am trying to backup, under windows, the osx partition into a (time machine) restorable format;

If this is possible, I would be able to then format the partition normally with disk utility in cmd+r mode; restore the backup which will give me a working partition with only some system files missing; and finally hopefully repair the system without reformatting, with application files intact.

Comment: Why not boot your Mac in target disk mode and connect to another computer to copy off the files? That might be cheaper than file recovery software but less risky than bringing a bootable installer and installing the macOS on top of the existing data. That should not delete anything, but since you’re not bootable, that might not work out.

Comment: I can access document files on the mac partition within windows and have already backed them up. However I dont think the various installed applications would still work if i simply copypastad them into the eventual reinstalled system.